# Spinors, punctured plane and principle frame bundle

Tags: mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, spinors

I am reading [Applied Conformal Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028) by Ginsparg. On page 72, while describing different boundary conditions on fermion he states the following.

> We shall choose to consider periodic $(P)$ and anti-periodic $(A)$ boundary conditions on the fermion $\Psi(z)$ as $z$ rotates by $2\pi$ about the origin, $$\Psi(\exp{(2\pi i) z}) = \pm \Psi(z).$$ Ultimately consideration of the two boundary conditions is dictated by the fact that spinors naturally live on a double cover of the punctured plane, and only bilinears in spinors, i.e. vectors, need transform as single-valued representations of the $2d$ Euclidean group. (On higher genus Riemann surfaces, spinors generally live in the spin bundle, i.e. the double cover of the principle frame bundle of the surface.)

Can someone elaborate on why do "spinors naturally live on a double cover of the punctured plane"? What is "principle frame bundle"? And also why "only bilinears in spinors" should "transform as
single-valued representations of the 2d Euclidean group"?

Comment: Not every lecture is a textbook. A textbook is supposed to *teach* by explaining more complex concepts using simpler terms. However, too often authors have no regard for the idea of teaching and simply state their own knowledge without any explanation. The principle difference between a good textbook and a crappy one is that the former is actually helpful. Can you read something else instead? At least for the start.